# Why JVM is giving error "incompatible type: String cannot be converted to char" and how to fix it without using other method?

Tags: java

Code:

```
public class Test2 {
  
  public static void main(String arga[]) {
    
    char arr[] = {"T","h","i","s"," ","i","s"," ","a"," ","t","e","s","t"};
    String str = new String(arr);
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Test2.java:5: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char
    char arr[] = {"T","h","i","s"," ","i","s"," ","a"," ","t","e","s","t"};
                  ^
```

Where's the error in the above code and how to fix it? please dont recommend me to use other method like: `String str = "This is a test";` etc etc. I want to know where's the error and how to fix this code, because I found this code on a book so I want to confirm if this is a printing mistake or something.

Comment: In `char arr[] = {"T","h","i","s"," ","i","s"," ","a"," ","t","e","s","t"};`
  replace `"` with `'`. Anything between `"` is a `String`, while single characters between `'` are `char`-literals.

Comment: `"T"` is a `String`. You need `'T'` instead

Comment: The JVM isn't giving you an error. The Java compiler is.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a `char` array with Strings. Here is the right syntax:

```
char arr[] = new char[]{'T','h','i','s',' ','i','s',' ','a',' ','t','e','s','t'};
String str = new String(arr);
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using string double quotes `"`. You want to use a single quote `'` when working with chars.